# Scratch file not running on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, scratch-file

I am trying to run a **Kotlin** [scratch file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html) in IntelliJ just like you would run a Java scratch file, but it doesn't work.

I created a new Kotlin scratch file, but can't run the code even after attempting the following:

- Create a `main` function and print something inside.
- Print something with `println` outside of the main function.
- Create a `class` with a `main` function inside and `println` something.

When I create a new kotlin project, the project runs fine. 
The issue happens only with scratch files. I am using kotlin plugin version 1.1.51 on IntelliJ 2017.1

As the screenshot shows, the icon that allows you to run kotlin code doesn't show up on the left of the editor window:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your observations are correct, and this is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10368).